# How to check the version of DolphinDB I am using?

Tags: database, docker, distributed, dolphindb

I deployed a distributed cluster successfully with DolphinDB Docker Package. But how to check what version of DolphinDB has been installed? I wonder where to specify the version to download so that I can use an earlier version.

Here's the tutorial: https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_CN/blob/master/docker_deployment.md

Answer (score 1):

I have a brief check, this project hard code to use `v0.95.3` version's DolphinDB. You had to modify `Dockerfile` of it to use old one.

**Steps as next:**

1. Download the deploy package from [here](https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_CN/blob/master/docker/DolphinDB-Docker-Compose.zip), just as the readme you give said.
2. Unzip this package, you will find a sub-package with the name `Dockerbuild`, enter into this folder, use a editor to modify the `Dockerfile`, change all `V0.95.3` to the version which you needed:

   ```
   FROM centos:latest

   RUN mkdir -p /data/ddb
   ADD http://www.dolphindb.com/downloads/DolphinDB_Linux64_V0.95.3.zip /data/ddb/
   RUN yum install -y unzip
   RUN yum install -y wget
   RUN (cd /data/ddb/ && unzip /data/ddb/DolphinDB_Linux64_V0.95.3.zip)
   RUN rm -rf /data/ddb/DolphinDB_Linux64_V0.95.3.zip
   RUN chmod 755 /data/ddb/server/dolphindb
   RUN mkdir -p /data/ddb/server/config
   ADD http://www.dolphindb.com/downloads/ZLIB_V0.95.0.zip /data/ddb/server/
   RUN (cd /data/ddb/server/ && unzip -n /data/ddb/server/ZLIB_V0.95.0.zip)
   RUN rm -rf /data/ddb/server/plugins/README.md
   RUN rm -rf /data/ddb/server/ZLIB_V0.95.0.zip
   ADD http://www.dolphindb.com/downloads/AWSS3_V0.95.0.zip /data/ddb/server/
   RUN (cd /data/ddb/server/ && unzip -n /data/ddb/server/AWSS3_V0.95.0.zip)
   RUN rm -rf /data/ddb/server/plugins/README.md
   RUN rm -rf /data/ddb/server/AWSS3_V0.95.0.zip
   ADD default_cmd /root/
   RUN chmod 755 /root/default_cmd
   ENTRYPOINT ["/root/default_cmd"]
   ```
3. Finally, follow the guide to build:

   ```
   cd ./DolphinDB-Docker-Compose/Dockerbuild
   docker build -t ddb:latest ./
   ```

Answer (score 1):

execute the following code in DolphinDB GUI

```
 version()
```